# How can I find a comprehensive list of USAID Cooperative Agreements by country?

Tags: data-request, usaidopen

I am looking for a dataset of all USAID awarded Cooperative Agreements by the country for the last 5 years (at least).

Answer (score 2):

The most comprehensive dataset of USAID assistance can be found at foreignassistance.gov. Specifically, by going to http://beta.foreignassistance.gov/agencies/USAID you can download all of the Agency's transactions currently available. I have been informed that the data is only complete for the last three years and anything past three years is partial as the site is still being developed. I was also informed that the data does not specifically designate between grants and cooperative agreements. If the information at FA.gov does not meet your needs, please send a request to opendata@usaid.gov and we will try to locate the specific information requested.